# Shared pointer to a const object thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading

A thread holds a shared_ptr to a const map object. This shared_ptr is occasionally updated by another thread. This shared_ptr could also be read by different threads.
Code snippet:

```
class SharedPointerHolder {
  private:
    shared_ptr<const map<int, string>> sptr_;
  public:
    SharedPointerHolder() : sptr_(make_shared<const map<int, string>>()) {};
    // new_sptr is guaranteed to be a valid pointer.
    void UpdateSharedPointer(shared_ptr<const map<int, string>>&& new_sptr) {
      if (!new_sptr) { return; }
      sptr_ = move(new_sptr);
    }
    void ReadSharedPointer() {
      // Since only UpdateSharedPointer() updates sptr_, it is guaranteed that sptr_ will always be valid. Still just in case, I have added this "if".
      if (!sptr_) {
        return;
      }
      local_sptr = sptr_;
      // Read the map object pointed by the local_sptr and perform some operations.
    }
}
```

`UpdateSharedPointer()` and `ReadSharedPointer()` can be called by different threads, but `UpdateSharedPointer()` will always be called after a certain time period, which ensures that the shared_ptr is not updated by two different threads at the same time.
My question is:

Does the `sptr_` need to be protected by a lock?

From what I read, a lock is required to protect the data pointed by the shared_ptr, but not for reading and updating the shared_ptr. Since in my case, the data is always const, I don't think a lock is required. It is possible that the private sptr_ is updated while we are in `ReadSharedPointer()`, but I am not concerned about that situation since I am fine working on a stale data.

Let's say if `UpdateSharedPointer()` is not necessarily invoked after certain time period and multiple threads might be contending to update the `sptr_` at the same time. Would I require a lock then? I understand that this might depend on whether my program can tolerate reading stale data, but is there any other race condition that I should be aware of?

**Use case:**
I am fine reading a stale map that was pointed by sptr_, in case sptr_ is updated by another thread. The most important thing that I am worried about is data corruption.

Thanks!

Comment: *"but UpdateSharedPointer() will always be called after a certain time period, which ensures that the shared_ptr is not updated by two different threads at the same time"* Beware that just delays are not enough to ensure synchronization. The compiler can make assumptions about your code with regards to the absence of synchronization and can optimize accordingly, which can break your code when it relies strictly on delays.

Comment: The thread safety guaranties of `std::shared_ptr` are only with regards to the control block. It means you don't have to synchronize multithreaded access between different instances of `std::shared_ptr` that share the same ownership when clearing or changing which object they refer to. It does not protect against concurrent access to a shared instance of `std::shared_ptr` as it seems you are asking about here.

Comment: C++20 introduces [`std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) which seems like what you want for this. But to avoid a logic error, you'll want to do `auto local_sptr = sptr_;` first and then compare `local_sptr` to `nullptr` second. Otherwise `sptr_` could change between the `if` and the `local_sptr` initialization.

Comment: And since you share that `std::atomic` you have to handle it's lifetime carefully. So you should have a `std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>>`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` is what I was looking for, but we haven't switched to C++20 yet. And using anything new has to go through a large amount of approvals. For now, I plan to use a readers-writers lock to protect the shared pointer: write lock in `UpdateSharedPointer()` and readers lock in `ReadSharedPointer()`. Operations on the const map object pointed by the shared_ptr should be safe since it is readonly. You also made a really good point about the compiler optimizations. Thanks!

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` is not a shared atomic. It is an atomic shared pointer. It's just like a single `std::shared_ptr` instance that multiple threads can try to read and reset concurrently.  Wrapping it in an additional `std::shared_ptr` defeats the purpose, making it once again unsafe for concurrent access.

Comment: @prashant If you can't use `atomic` then yeah, you basically have no choice but to fall back to using a lock.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Indeed, it is not a shared atomic, there is no such thing as a shared atomic. That is my point. The use case shares it between threads. It either has to be a global or passed by reference or as pointer. The outer `std::shared_ptr` ensures the atomic is not deleted before the last reference. The `std::atomic` makes it safe for concurrent access and the inner `std:shared_ptr` keeps the inner map alive till the last reference to that iteration of the map goes out of scope. Note: the outer shared_ptr should to be copied to each thread, not shared or you just repeat the problem.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow You seem to miss the purpose of atomic here. The question concerns a single instance of `std::shared_ptr` where multiple threads can read which is the shared object or change which is the shared object. Making the `shared_ptr` an `atomic` makes that safe. And there is such a thing as a shared atomic, it looks like `std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<int>>`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's what I said. Except the object that is shared here is not `int` but `shared_ptr<const map<int, string>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, access to `sptr_` needs to be synchronized.

Only modification of the `shared_ptr`'s control block is atomic.  Modification of the `shared_ptr` itself is not.  If a single `shared_ptr` object is shared across threads then it will generally need some form of synchronization.

Consider this logical diagram of multiple `shared_ptr`s sharing ownership of a single object:

```
shared_ptr p1          shared_ptr p2           shared_ptr p3
┌───────────────────┐  ┌───────────────────┐  ┌───────────────────┐
│                   │  │                   │  │                   │
│ control_block_ptr │  │ control_block_ptr │  │ control_block_ptr │
│                   │  │                   │  │                   │
└─────────────┬─────┘  └─┬─────────────────┘  └┬──────────────────┘
              │ ┌────────┘                     │
              │ │ ┌────────────────────────────┘
control block ▼ ▼ ▼            owned object
┌──────────────────┐           ┌────────────────────────┐
│                  │           │                        │
│ object_ptr       ├──────────►│                        │
│                  │           │                        │
├──────────────────┤           └────────────────────────┘
│                  │
│ strong_ref_count │
│                  │
├──────────────────┤
│                  │
│ weak_ref_count   │
│                  │
└──────────────────┘
```

If `p3` is assigned to, then its `control_block_ptr` gets overwritten to point to the control block of the `shared_ptr` on the right-hand side of the assignment.  This is a member of the `shared_ptr` itself, so this modification is not thread-safe.  If any other thread is accessing `p3` at the same time you will have a data race, and the behavior of your program becomes undefined.

On the other hand, if you make a copy of `p2` in thread A at the same time you assign to `p3` in thread B, then that *will* be safe.  Both will need to modify the `strong_ref_count` in their shared control block (the copy of `p2` needs to increment it, and `p3` needs to decrement it), but that ref count modification will be done atomically.  You are guaranteed to get the correct result and no data race will occur.

Comment: Did you mean "You are _guaranteed_ to get the correct result and no data race will occur"?

Comment: @prashant Yes, fixed

Answer (score 1):

> `UpdateSharedPointer()` will always be called after a certain time period, which ensures that the `shared_ptr` is not updated by two different threads at the same time. My question is:
>
> Does the `sptr_` need to be protected by a lock?

Even if only 1 thread ever updates what the `shared_ptr` is pointing at, if there is ever a *possibility* that other threads may read the `shared_ptr`'s pointer at the same time that a thread is updating the pointer, then you MUST protect the `shared_ptr` with a lock.  Period.  This is no different than any other kind of resource shared over thread boundaries.

> Let's say if `UpdateSharedPointer()` is not necessarily invoked after certain time period and multiple threads might be contending to update the `sptr_` at the same time. Would I require a lock then?

Yes, absolutely.

Comment: So basically the shared_ptrs don't guarantee if multiple threads update the same instance, the update will be atomic?

Comment: @prashant Correct.  Only the control block is thread-safe.  Multiple threads copying and/or resetting _different_ `shared_ptr` objects that share ownership of the same object is safe, but multiple threads working with the same `shared_ptr` object is not, and will need synchronization.

Comment: @MilesBudnek. I see. So what gets updated when we assign (or call assignment operator) to a shared_ptr?  I know that the control block needs to be updated and it has to be protected, but what other member variable of shared_ptr makes the updating unsafe? All I find online is "If multiple threads of execution access the same instance of shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur", but it doesn't really tell us what makes the updating unsafe.

Comment: @prashant A `shared_ptr` essentially only has one member: a pointer to its control block (technically it also has a pointer directly to its owned object to support the aliasing constructor, but ignore that).  Assigning one `shared_ptr` to another (or `reset`ing a `shared_ptr`) overwrites that pointer to the control block, and that pointer is not atomic.  Essentially, directly modifying a `shared_ptr` in any way is not thread safe, but modifying the control block itself is (since that is shared by many `shared_ptr`s).